# Is there a bootchart-style analyzer for what happens AFTER you log in?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, login

[Bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/) is an excellent tool for seeing what goes on when your computer boots. However, it only charts up to the login screen. Is there any way to analyze what is happening when I actually log in? I would like to see which startup applications are taking the most time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu Karmic, bootchart is set by default to continue for 45 seconds after booting is finished. This allows you to analyze what happens after you log in.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a good starting point is http://www.gnome.org/~lcolitti/gnome-startup/analysis/

Answer (score 1):

Also probably interesting is the effort made by [moblin](http://moblin.org/projects/fast-boot) to [boot in 5 seconds](http://lwn.net/Articles/299483/).

Answer (score 0):

The recently announced [timechart](http://blog.fenrus.org/?p=5) seems interesting. I can't seem to find a download link for it, though.